# Securing asp.net webform cookie not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

I want to secure cookie in a ways even if login cookie is stolen it should still now work,

I am using default asp.net membership in web-form .net framework 4.0 to protect some pages on website, so only registered users can access pages after they log in properly. But if Middle man steals the cookie then they can still log in.

How can i protect cookie from being stolen

I did following from my side

- I am now using https on website
- Second i added following code in web.config `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />`

Even after taking these message i was able to log in to secured website by just adding cookie name & cookie value in different browser without actually using log in form. If i took above two steps then why is not my cookie encrypted so that even if cookie is stolen it should not work.. am i doing anything wrong

Comment: The first line of protection is using https, if a third person can avoid it or MITM it, there is nothing stopping from stealing cookies. There are no other protections in place in your setup to avoid such thing to happen. The only other thing you can turn on or adopt is using HSTS, there is not much more really AFAIK.

Comment: I am using it over https and when i copy `.ASPXAUTH` value and enter same in different browser i am able to access to secure page. not sure where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using the best cookie protection in asp.net. The `httpOnlyCookies` setting prevents any (perhaps injected) javascript on your site from accessing the token, and the `requireSSL` setting prevents the browser from sending them over an non `https` connection.

This is generally pretty good, as good or better than most websites.

Anyone who can Man-In-The-Middle the connection, or who otherwise can access the cookie value on your machine can still access your site, but there is no standard effective defence against this.

Presumably in order to copy the cookie, you accessed the developer tools, and directly copied the value. Most attackers cannot do this without already having compromised the end user's machine, for example with a malicious browser extension. Your `httpOnly` flag prevents them from doing this with a script.

Likewise you may have installed a proxy like Fiddler to inspect the traffic, or a business might have a http proxy that filters content, but there will be a trusted certificate installed on you machine that allows this inspection to take place. Without it, the browser would not allow the page to load.

There are a couple of things you can do to improve it further, you could look at [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) however it has serious consequences if you get things wrong. TLS 1.3 also contains extra protections, but it is brand new so support for it is very variable.

Any regular ajax request made to your domain will still send the cookie, but the javascript cannot access the content of the cookie. Likewise frameworks that use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) can be configured to send the credentials too. Any third party plugin that needs to send **your** authentication cookie to a **different** domain is doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there a way if i can protect it further so MITM cant have access to it.

Comment: Ah, So you mean due to XSS injection hacker cant use document.cookie js function what if i am using third part plugin which need access to their cookies, will it block JS from createing and accessing cookie

Comment: I am using Developer Inspect tool to copy past cookie, I am not using any fiddlers for any traffic monitoring